# Not able to connect Anypoint Studio to Anypoint Platform

Tags: mule, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, anypoint-platform

I am not able to connect **anypoint studio** to **anypoint platform** in ubuntu.
Blank screen comes up whenever I try to click on configure credentials.

Attaching the screenshot, can anyone please help.
[image]

Comment: Which version of Anypoint Studio? Is it a new installation?

Comment: Yes Aled, I am using Anypoint 7

Comment: The full version is important. Is it 7.8, 7.11, 7.15, etc? The more complete information you provide the better chances someone may answer your question. Is it a new installation? Did it work before? Did it stop working after something changed? Is it running in a corporate network?

Comment: It is 7.15.0, yes it is a new installation, I was following the handson from training.mulesoft.com, but  I am stuck as I am not able to connect to anypoint platform, I even tried with version 6.6 but in that too, same issue is occurring.

Comment: Try from some other operating system (Windows or Mac) from the same network to discard it is a networking issue. If Studio in a different OS can connect it may be a problem with the Linux distribution of Studio.

Answer (score 0):

On occasion, I've encountered an empty screen in the 7.11 and 7.12 versions of AnyPoint Studio on Mac. I found that letting the User Login window remain open for about a minute or two resolved the problem for me. It might be worthwhile to attempt this approach and observe if it provides any assistance.

My speculation for this occurrence is that the initial loading of the browser within the user login window might be experiencing a delay.